# jQuery Mobile, page change on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery mobile and want to validate a form.
I've given a class of `paymentDetailForm` to the form.

```
<form method="post" action="demo.java" class="paymentDetailForm">
```

The submit button in the form has an id of `paymentConfirm`
then in the javascript, I'm using this code:

```
$("#paymentConfrim").click(function() {
 $( ".paymentDetailForm" ).submit(function( event ) {
   if(!validatePaymentDetailForm()){ // if false comes from validation
     return false;
   }
   else{
     $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer("change", "#successPage", {});
     return true;
    }
 });
```

});

Here `validatePaymentDetailForm` is a custom validation function I've wrote to  validate form fields. It returns false if form doesn't validate, otherwise it returns true.

On successful form submission, I'm trying to redirect the user to success message page. The id of the sub-page is `successPage`, but the code shown above isn't working.

```
$(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer("change", "#successPage", {});
```

Console shows this error, while this line is executed:
`Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: mobile-pagecontainer`

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using an older version of jQuery Mobile ver 1.2. Apparently jQuery pagecontainer widget was introduced in jQuery Mobile ver 1.4. 
I couldn't change the jQuery mobile version, so I used changePage() function.

This is the code, I used to make the page transition work:

```
$("#paymentConfrim").click(function() {
  $( ".paymentDetailForm" ).submit(function( event ) {
  if(!validatePaymentDetailForm()){ // if false comes from validation
     return false;
  }
  else{
      $.mobile.changePage( "#submissionConfirmation", {} );
     return true;
   }
});
```